# In "The Amazing Race 16, Leg 11", why did the show use the name "Garden Bridge" instead of "Waibaidu Bridge"?

Tags: amazing-race

In "The Amazing Race 16, Leg 11", the teams were in Shanghai, and they were told to go to the "Garden Bridge", in stead of the more common name "Waibaidu Bridge".

Most Shanghainess only know the name "Waibaidu Bridge" but not "Garden Bridge", so the teams had a hard time to find the bridge.

Why didn't the show use the more common name "Waibaidu Bridge"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To make it more difficult for them.** That's what was challenging about it. From an [online recap](http://news.nationalpost.com/2010/05/02/recap-the-amazing-race-16-episode-11/):

> The teams have to find something called the Garden Bridge, which Phil informs us is only known locally by its Chinese name. This turns out to be problematic, as the teams ask the locals if they know the way to it, and of course none of them have heard of it.

Phil can be really mean sometimes. ;)

Comment: The clues preparation are the responsibility of other production crew. Phil cannot be mean, since he doesn't make the clues, he only reveals them.

Comment: @wbogacz I'm not being serious... The contestants always jokingly berate Phil for giving them a hard time.